# Initialize class instance in a loop over a list

Tags: python

I have a class where I assign a rating to each instance.

```
class Team:

def __init__(self, rating):
    "Initialize team with rating"
    self.rating = rating
```

I would like to be able to loop over a list of ratings, and create an instance for each rating, so if I have a list of ratings and team names, something like this:

```
scores = [10, 11, 12, 13]
teams = ['tm0', 'tm1', 'tm2', 'tm3']

for t, s in zip(teams, scores):
    t = Team(s)

tm2.rating    # returns 12
```

The above is not defining an instance of Team like I want it to.

I am new to Python so suspect there is an easy fix, or a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to want a `dict` that maps each team *name* to an instance of `Team`.

```
scores = [10, 11, 12, 13]
team_names = ['tm0', 'tm1', 'tm2', 'tm3']
teams = {t: Team(s) for t, s in zip(team_names, scores)}

assert teams['tm0'].rating == 10
```

Comment: `z2` isn't really necessary, *unless* you need to save a reference to the object before assigning something else to the key with something like `teams['tm2'] = Team(15)`.

Comment: Sorry, I  just deleted the comment you replied to as I thought your edit (which I missed) resolved my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want here with exec:

```
for t,s in zip(teams, scores):
    exec(f"{t} = Team({s})")
```

Comment: Can I ask why this is being downvoted? It works perfectly for me - is it because it is un-Pythonic in some way?

Comment: Generally speaking I would avoid using exec, as it executes an arbitrary command, which could have unexpected consequences.